# Apache mod_proxy sticksession not working. Balancer seems to ignore it

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I've turned on sticksessions in apache. Config is at:
http://pastie.org/private/7e9idebbk5jhmsyd8r4kew

The logs show apache finding the cookie but it still doesn't remain sticky to one of the servers in the balancer. Filtered log is:

http://pastie.org/2096930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSESSIONID` cookies don't appear to contain a route, just the session ID.

They need to provide that information in their cookies in order for Apache to know what member to send to; such as `771F23205D79E225993EDC2FD884A5C6.nfl1`.

What's the back-end web service?  It'll be a setting there, if it supports it.  Alternatively, you can have Apache set a cookie directly for tracking the stickiness, avoiding the need to use the back-end's session ID.  Info on doing that [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#example).

Comment: jboss is the back end.The ever so modern 4.0.5 version. Digging some more. Thanks

Comment: Should be able to set a `jvmRoute` in the `<Engine>` config.